# In college sports, does a redshirt have to sit a whole season?

Tags: american-football, basketball, collegiate

More specifically to college football or even basketball, is a player who is redshirted allowed to play at all during their redshirt season?

Comment: What does *redshirted* mean?

Comment: basically a college player has 4 years of eligibility to play sports (one for every year of college). A team has the option to "Redshirt" a player for one year out of the four years the player is at school. If you are "redshirting" a year you cannot play in any of your teams games but you dont lose a year of eligibility. Its usually used on incoming freshman so they can develop another year but still be able to play 4 years. dont know if that makes sense or not

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Being redshirted doesn't commit the player to not playing the entire season; the team/player can change their decision part way through the year, but that revokes the benefit of having been redshirted (ie, that year would now count against their eligibility).

If the player plays in at least one game, that year counts towards their eligibility limits.

There is an exception if you start a season as an active player, and then get injured shortly into the season. You can retroactively be classified as a redshirt for that season.

Comment: "If the player plays in at least one game, that year counts towards their eligibility limits." true except if the player is injured.. you can apply for an injury redshirt with the Ncaa. Other than that good answer +1

Comment: I think you have to apply to the NCAA and they decide whether to award you an injury redshirt or not

Answer (score 3):

This can vary a lot between sports so I'm not sure if there's a clear answer, but for the most part, once you've chosen to redshirt, you don't play anymore, unless you want to forfeit the redshirt.

In outdoor track, for example, people can red-shirt even if they've already run up to two competitions, and as long as it's before a certain date, and they have an injury.

Comment: So I guess a major factor is the sport they play in?